# how to implement UITableView inside container programmaticaly?

Tags: swift, uitableview, containers

im trying to implement UITableView inside a container **without using storyboard.**
first i created this:

```
let phoneNumsContainerView : UITableView = {
  let view = UITableView()
  view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  return view

}()
```

then, in "ViewDidLoad" i called:

```
 view.addSubview(phoneNumsContainerView)
```

My question is, how/where do i implement the tableView functions (cellForRowAt indexPath for an example..)
and how can i create a custom cell to this tableview.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call below method set `dataSource` and implement other mandatory tableView datasource methods as well:-

```
phoneNumsContainerView.dataSource = self //Inside your Viewdidload method

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let Cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "ReuseIdentifier")
Cell.textLabel.text = "SomeValue"
return Cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! what if i want to add more then one container like this?

Comment: You mean more tableview??

Comment: In that case you can have reference of multiple tableView. So inside your dataSource method(cellForRowAt) you can put if check for multiple tableView eg. if tableView == tableView1 { }. You do not have to implement multiple times same tableView methods.